# Sorting in a query based on another querys AVG

Tags: mysql

This is my current query to grab my deals:

```
SELECT deals.*, SUM(orders.cost) AS 'revenue' FROM deals
LEFT JOIN orders ON (orders.deal_id = deals.id)
WHERE 1
AND (orders.status = 'new' OR orders.status = 'delivered')
GROUP BY deals.ID
ORDER BY revenue ASC
```

Now this works great and i can sort this query by (order by) whatever field I wish in orders or deals table.

Then when i loop through the deals and display them with a foreach(),
I have this query to grab average review stars from customers for a deal:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(stars)) as 'avg_stars' FROM deals_reviews WHERE deal_id = *THE DEAL_ID* AND active = '1'
```

Now I would like to sort all the deals ASC/DESC out from the average stars.

To do this it require for me to merge that query with the above one, and when i need to display the avg_stars I grab this value from the first and only query and not a second query.

How can I have that query 'merged' into that first one? So when thats done we can just do ORDER BY avg_stars DESC and it'll sort by this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand right, but this should be the solution

```
SELECT deals.*, SUM(orders.cost) AS 'revenue' FROM deals
LEFT JOIN orders ON (orders.deal_id = deals.id)
LEFT JOIN deals_reviews ON (deals.id = deals_reviews.deal_id AND active = '1')
WHERE 1
AND (orders.status = 'new' OR orders.status = 'delivered')
GROUP BY deals.ID
ORDER BY ROUND(AVG(stars)) as 'avg_stars' ASC
```

Comment: Hello it did work when I took the ROUND(AVG(stars)) as 'avg_stars' up to the SELECT and then ORDER BY avg_stars. However check my updated question the query above, I need tocheck that active = 1 in the deals_reviws, how would i do this ?